# Extracting rows from a pandas dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames. One dataframe (A) looks like:

```
Name     begin    stop    ID      
Peter     30       150    1      
Hugo     4500     6000    2      
Jennie    300      700    3
```

The other dataframe (B) looks like

```
entry     string      
89         aa      
568        bb     
938437     cc
```

I want to accomplish two tasks here:

1. I want to get a list of indices for rows (from dataframe B) for which **entry** column falls in the interval (specified by **begin** and **stop** column) in dataframe A.
   The result for this task will be:

```
lst = [0,1]. ### because row 0 of B falls in interval of row 1 in A and row 1 of B falls in interval of row 3 of A.
```

2. The indices that I get from task **1**, I want to remove it from dataframe B to create a new dataframe. Thus, the new dataframe will look like:

```
entry     string          
938437     cc
```

How can I accomplish these two tasks?

Comment: how big are your two dataframes?

Comment: Dataframe B is of shape (14011296, 132) and dataframe A is of shape (63275, 12)

Comment: in dataframe A, do you have overlaps in the intervals?

Comment: No there are no overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
l = (pd.merge_asof(dfB['entry'].reset_index() #to keep original index after merge
                      .sort_values('entry'), #mandatory to use this merge_asof
                   dfA[['begin','stop']].sort_values('begin'),
                   left_on='entry', right_on='begin',
                   direction='backward') # begin lower than entry
       .query('stop >= entry') # keep only where entry lower than stop
       ['index'].tolist()
    )
print(l)
# Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')

new_df = dfB.loc[dfB.index.difference(l)]
print(new_df)
#     entry string
# 2  938437     cc
```

Now if you don't need the list onf index and that you real goal is the new_df, then you can do directly

```
new_df = (pd.merge_asof(dfB.sort_values('entry'), 
                        dfA[['begin','stop']].sort_values('begin'),
                        left_on='entry', right_on='begin',
                        direction='backward')
            .query('stop < entry') #here different inegality
            .drop(['begin','stop'], axis=1) #clean the result
            .reset_index(drop=True)
         )
print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `between()` method and `tolist()` method to get list of indexes:

```
lst=B[B['entry'].between(A.loc[0,'begin'],A.loc[len(A)-1,'stop'])].index.tolist()
```

Finally make use of `isin()` method and boolean masking:

```
result=B[~B.index.isin(lst)]
```